# Any reason to use private instead of private final static on the LogBack Logger?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, logback

When instantiating Logger in a Spring Controller, is there any reason to declare it as a **static final**? The Logger is not used outside MyController.class. I've seen both examples in use, but can't see why I should use one or the other.

```
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);
```

vs

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);
```

Comment: better get rid of this variable entirely and use [Logger](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log/apidocs-0.7.7/com/jcabi/log/Logger.html) from [jcabi-log](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log/), which is a static wrapper around SLF4J

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Personally, I use

```
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

The main advantage of this is I can cut and paste this into new classes without having to change the name of the class.

As for whether or not they should be static, please see [Should Logger members of a class be declared as static?](http://slf4j.org/faq.html#declared_static), from the slf4j website, which says:

We used to recommend that loggers members be declared as instance variables instead of static. **After further analysis, we no longer recommend one approach over the other.**

Taken from that page:

### Advantages for declaring loggers as static

1. common and well-established idiom
2. less CPU overhead: loggers are retrieved and assigned only once, at hosting class initialization
3. less memory overhead: logger declaration will consume one reference per class

### Disadvantages for declaring loggers as static

1. For libraries shared between applications, not possible to take advantage of repository selectors. It should be noted that if the SLF4J binding and the underlying API ships with each application (not shared between applications), then each application will still have its own logging environment.
2. not IOC-friendly

### Advantages for declaring loggers as instance variables

1. Possible to take advantage of repository selectors even for libraries shared between applications. However, repository selectors only work if the underlying logging system is logback-classic. Repository selectors do not work for the SLF4J+log4j combination.
2. IOC-friendly

### Disadvantages for declaring loggers as instance variables

1. Less common idiom than declaring loggers as static variables
2. higher CPU overhead: loggers are retrieved and assigned for each instance of the hosting class
3. higher memory overhead: logger declaration will consume one reference per instance of the hosting class

### Explanation

Static logger members cost a single variable reference for all instances of the class whereas an instance logger member will cost a variable reference for every instance of the class. For simple classes instantiated thousands of times there might be a noticeable difference.

However, more recent logging systems, e.g log4j or logback, support a distinct logger context for each application running in the application server. Thus, even if a single copy of log4j.jar or logback-classic.jar is deployed in the server, the logging system will be able to differentiate between applications and offer a distinct logging environment for each application.

More specifically, each time a logger is retrieved by invoking LoggerFactory.getLogger() method, the underlying logging system will return an instance appropriate for the current application. Please note that within the same application retrieving a logger by a given name will always return the same logger. For a given name, a different logger will be returned only for different applications.

If the logger is static, then it will only be retrieved once when the hosting class is loaded into memory. If the hosting class is used in only in one application, there is not much to be concerned about. However, if the hosting class is shared between several applications, then all instances of the shared class will log into the context of the application which happened to first load the shared class into memory - hardly the behavior expected by the user.

For more information, see that page.

Comment: Good tip about the this.getClass()

Comment: Good explanation on the static part, but what about the final part? Is 'static final' preferred over 'static' ? Thanks.

Comment: @Dimitri Dewaele For the logger, use final and initialize it right away. This way, you prevent any cases like NPE because you forgot do initialize it. One exception to this is when you precisely want to change the logger. For instance, you might want to replace it by a spy logger to verify your generated log messages during your unit tests.

Comment: In order not to copy and paste you can use code templates. All modern ide's support it.

Answer (score 3):

Just `private` field will be initialised for each instance of your class. However, `private static` field will be initialised one time per class.

In case of logger most probably (depends on logging implementation), in both cases you will get the same instance of logger and you won't use noticeably bigger amount of memory. But still `LoggerFactory.getLogger` will be called with every object you create.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; so there's only one logger for the class, instead of one per instance.

Either way it's private, so using it outside the class has nothing to do with it--that's not what `static final` does.

Answer (score -4):

I'm just curious about this line:

```
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);
```

Is it:

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class)
```

or:

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class.getName());
```

Because the first one will return "class" before the real name:

```
class com.example.MyController (instead of com.example.MyController)
```

Comment: This is a question, not an answer